# Altium custom parameters not syncing with smart BOM

Tags: altium

One of my component suppliers wanted to know the requirements per component for searching alternative components.

So I decided to create a column=AltRequirements in my BOM excel template

First I added an AltRequirements | 1% parameter to one resistor and this was shown properly in the smart BOM.

Then I started using [Find similar objects] to select all 10k resistors.
Used the Parameter manager and give all resistors in there the 1% value inside the AltRequirements column
Executed the changes.

Somehow it started to get out of sync.
The smartBOM incorrectly shows [No Param],1%

I tried many things, deleted the entire column in the parameter manager
Re-added it
But I never get it in sync

I have 17 10k resistors, parameter manager shows me 17 lines, every cell in the AltRequirements column has 1% value in it.
But still smartBOM shows [No Param],1% even after refreshing, restart Altium, import changes into PCB doc, etc

Anyone else experience bugs with this?

Comment: Are you referring to ActiveBOM? There's not a SmartBOM in Altium (that I know of anyway).

Comment: Which designators are listed in the ActiveBOM row, and are they all set properly (is it accidentally pulling in 18+ items, not the 17 desired)? Are you using variants, and are any relevant parameters varied?

Comment: Ah yes ActiveBOM. Next workday, Altium opened with a bunch of errors and sync worked again. Tried to report it to Altium but man such a frustrating company. I hope they will taken over by Autodesk soon. Do you guys pay the yearly subscription fee without a doubt?